# Ajax Sending data (JSON) throught POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Someone can see why it shows the error Maximum call stack size exceeded? And why is not working the script? UPDATE: I added the php code that don't put the value "domain" and I updated the JS code.

```
    function addentrys() {
    var nwentry =  {};
    el = document.getElementById('addname').value;
    eldmn = document.getElementById('adddomain').value;
    nwentry.name = el;
    nwentry.domain = eldmn;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/domain',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: nwentry,
        succes: function(data) {
            alert('Ok')
        }
    })
}
```

php:

```
//ADD
$app->post('/domain', function () {
    $jsonContents = file_get_contents('data/data.json');
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $domain = $_POST['domain'];
    $data = json_decode($jsonContents, true);
    $last_item = end($data);
    $last_item_id = $last_item['id'];
    $data[] = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'domain' => $domain,
        'id' => $last_item_id+1
    );
    $json = json_encode($data);
    file_put_contents('data/data.json', $json);
    return $this->response->withRedirect('../index.html');
});
```

Comment: How are you calling method addentrys()? Also you not using value of document.getElementById('addname')

Comment: I'm calling it whit a button on the same form than "addname"

Comment: Error message shows that probably you calling this method recursively. So you check your click event

Comment: change this line of code:   nwentry.name = el.value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing control object not the value to ajax. try below code

```
    function addentrys() {
    var nwentry =  {};
    el = document.getElementById('addname')
    nwentry.name = el.value;
    var data = JSON.stringify(nwentry)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/domain',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: (nwentry),
        succes: function(result) {
            console.log(result)
         }
     })
  }
```

Comment: if I want to add one value more to nwentry how can I do it? If I add another, the php didn't add nothing

Comment: nwentry.anothername = anotherelement.value;

Comment: Yeah when I put it, it don't add nothing

Comment: If I put nwentry.anothername = anotherelement, the script add the name and put empty the "anothername" but if I add nwentry.anothername = anotherelement.value it don't add nothing

Comment: Please update your code. may be your element is null. check document.getElementById('anotherelement')

Comment: Forget it now works, the problem was there weren't the id adddomain, if you update your answer I'll accept it

Comment: thats good :). although I already said that may be your element is null

Answer (score 1):

```
function addentrys() {
    var nwentry =  {};
    el = document.getElementById('addname').value;
    nwentry.name = el;
    var data = JSON.stringify(nwentry)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/domain',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: (nwentry),
        succes: function(result) {
            console.log(result)
    }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. Check `success` function typo and sending `data` varaible, not `nwentry` object

```
function addentrys() {
var nwentry =  {};
el = document.getElementById('addname')
nwentry.name = el;
var data = JSON.stringify(nwentry)
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/domain',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: it tells null when I add the content